# map . foldr function composition - Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, fold, function-composition

So, let's straight to the point.

```
:t (map.foldr)
(map.foldr) :: (a1 -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a1] -> a]
```

What is [[a1] -> a]?
I'm really trying to understand this composition, so I was doing this:

```
-- map.foldr

    map.foldr :: (a1 -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a1] -> a]

    map :: (a1 -> b1) -> [a1] -> [b1]
    (.) :: (y -> w) -> (x -> y) -> x -> w
    foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b

    y = (a1 -> b1)      w = ([a1] -> [b1])
    x = (a -> b -> b)   y = (b -> [a] -> b)

    y = (a1 -> b1)  
    y = (b -> [a] -> b)
_________________________
```

What happens in this point? Thank you!

Comment: `foldr` type is wrong, should be `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer this question it's good to recall what `foldr` and `map` do.

The more complicated of the two is `foldr`, which has type

```
--              list to be folded
--                              v
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
--             ^          ^
--folding function        terminal value
```

The list to be folded is really a chain of conses `(:)` and a terminal empty list:

```
1 : 2 : 3 : []
```

The action of `foldr` is to replace the `:` and `[]` constructors with the folding function and the terminal value, respectively:

```
foldr (+) 0 (1 : 2 : 3 : []) == 1 + 2 + 3 + 0
```

---

The `map` function is simpler. One way of thinking of it is as taking a function and a list, and applying the function to every argument of the list:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
--        ^         ^
-- function         list
```

However, you can also think of it as taking a function, and lifting it to be a function that acts on lists instead:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ( [a] -> [b] )
--        ^              ^
-- function              function on lists
```

---

What does it mean to compose these two functions, `map . foldr`? Note that this is just applying the functions one after the other - in particular,

```
(map . foldr) f == map (foldr f)
```

Since you apply `foldr` first, you must be applying it to a function `f :: a -> b -> b`, and you get back another function:

```
foldr f :: b -> [a] -> b
--         ^     ^
--terminal val   list to be folded
```

Now you apply `map`, which lifts the function to act on lists:

```
map (foldr f) :: [b] -> [[a] -> b]
--                ^          ^
--list of terminal vals      functions that fold lists
```

This type looks odd, but it's valid. Now instead of a single terminal value, you give it a list of terminal values, and you get a list of folding functions back - one for each terminal value that you supplied.

---

To make it clearer we could look at a particular function, `(+)`, which has type

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

If we substitute that into the equation above, we get

```
(map . foldr) (+) :: Num a => [a] -> [[a] -> a]
--                             ^          ^
--         list of terminal vals          functions that fold lists
```

If we now apply it to the list `[0, 1, 2]` we get a list of three functions:

```
(map . foldr) (+) [0,1,2] :: Num a => [[a] -> a]
```

We can use the `map ($x)` idiom to apply each of the functions in the list to a particular argument. It has to be a list of numbers, and I'll choose `[3,4,5]`. Watch carefully:

```
> map ($[3,4,5]) ((map.foldr) (+) [0,1,2])
[12, 13, 14]
```

The list `[3,4,5]` was folded three times using `(+)` as the folding function, and each time with a different terminal value:

```
3 + 4 + 5 + 0 == 12
3 + 4 + 5 + 1 == 13
3 + 4 + 5 + 2 == 14
```

When the terminal value is `0`, we simply get the sum of the values: `3 + 4 + 5 == 12`. When the terminal value is `1` we get one more than the sum of the values (`13`) and when the terminal value is `2` we get two more than the sum of the values (`14`).

Comment: Where can I find more information about the "map ($x)" idiom? I cannot understand it. Oh, and thanks for the answer, really helpful :)

Comment: The operator `$` is defined by `f $ x = f x`, i.e. it applies the function on its left to the argument on its right. It is strictly unnecessary, but it is helpful in two ways: 1. the `$` operator has lowest precedence and associates right (unlike function application which has highest precedence and associates left) so you can write `f a $ g b $ h c` instead of `f a (g b (h c))`, and 2. you can use it in a section, so you can write `($f)` instead of `\a -> f a`. The code `map ($x)` therefore means the same as `map (\a -> x a)`.

Answer (score 2):

To continue where you left off, the two definitions of `y` must be equal:

```
y = (a1 -> b1) = (b ->  [a] -> b)
               = (b -> ([a] -> b))
```

so we can conclude that:

```
a1 = b
b1 = [a] -> b
```

The function composition has been supplied two function arguments, so the resulting type is just:

```
x -> w
```

But we know:

```
x = a -> b -> b
w = [a1] -> [b1] = [b] -> [[a] -> b]
```

So, the result type is:

```
(x -> w) = ((a -> b -> b) -> ([b] -> [[a] -> b]))
         =  (a -> b -> b) ->  [b] -> [[a] -> b]
```

which is congruent to:

```
(a1 -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a1] -> a]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map.foldr :: (a1 -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a1] -> a]

map :: (a1 -> b1) -> [a1] -> [b1]
(.) :: (y -> w) -> (x -> y) -> x -> w
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b

-- if you substitute: x = (a -> b -> b)   y = (b -> [a] -> b)
-- then you get for map :: (b -> ([a] -> b)) -> [b] -> [[a] -> b]
-- so if composition operator applied:
map . foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> [b] -> [[a] -> b]
```